# What is wrong with the following Python code -- trying to insert into a database?

Tags: mysql, python

This works in MySQL Workbench:

```
insert into nametest (name,surname) values('John''Krailling');
```

I am trying a get similar result with Pycharm with the following code:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root", # your username
                  passwd="iop", # your password
                  db="new_schema")# name of the data base
cur=db.cursor()

cur.execute("insert into nametest(name,surname) values('John', 'Green')")
```

The  entry is added in Pycharm, but not in the table in the underlying database.

Comment: This: `insert into nametest (name,surname) values('John''Krailling');` will fail - lack of comma between the two names. You are missing a semi-colon at the end of your Python statement. If that's not the issue, could it be failure to commit?

Comment: Verace, thanks for the answer. The semi-colon seems to make no difference. I thought commit is only needed in a transaction?

Comment: Depending on the API transactions may  or may not be explicit. I don't know what MySQLdb does behind the scenes - check the documentation. I have to learn Python shortly, so I'll be in your shoes pretty soon! :-)

Comment: Verace: db.commit was the answer! Nice weekend,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this is my table:

`mysql> desc name_test;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| fname | varchar(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sname | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

and this is the code to insert the data:

```
    import mysql.connector

    db = mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1", # your host, usually localhost
             user="root", # your username
              passwd="", # your password
              db="music")# name of the data base
    cur=db.cursor()

    q = "insert into name_test(fname,sname) values(%s, %s)"
    v = { "bob", "smith" }

    cur.execute(q,v) #runs the query
    db.commit() #ensures that its saved
    cur.close() #closes the cursor
    db.close() #closes the connection
```

source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, Dan! that solved the problem. Nice weekend, Robert